# how to make already exposed service not to be exposed?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I deployed a (LoadBalancer) service for a pod on my minikube cluster, then exposed it via `minikube service [my_service]` command. Now I tried to "turn off the exposure" but couldn't find any way to do this, except deleting it what I would like to avoid. Is it possible to just turn off the exposure, not deleting (and redeploying) the existing already exposed service?

Comment: Try changing from `type=LoadBalancer` to `type=ClusterIP` via `kubectl`.

Comment: If you have the YAML file that describes the service checked into source control, you can edit that file and run `kubectl apply -f the-service.yaml` to change its configuration (or `helm upgrade` if you're using Helm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Background

In Kubernetes documentation regarding [ServiceTypes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types), you can find information that if you want to expose your cluster outside you have to use [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) or [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer).

If you want to keep your service/application in cluster, you should use `ClusterIP`:

> Exposes the Service on a `cluster-internal IP`. **Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster**. This is the default ServiceType.

Depends on your version, you can edit it or use workaround. For example in K8s **1.16** you won't be able as some errors might occurs.

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.8.0.1      <none>          443/TCP        3d20h
my-nginx     LoadBalancer   10.8.14.224   34.121.77.108   80:32039/TCP   3m16s
$ kubectl patch service my-nginx -p '{"spec":{"type":"ClusterIP"}}'
The Service "my-nginx" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Forbidden: may not be used when `type` is 'ClusterIP'
```

#### Solutions

However as you are using `Minikube` so I guess you are using newer version (1.20), so you can change it using:

1. **kubectl edit**

`kubectl edit svc <yourSvcName>` and change type to `ClusterIP`.
It will open `Vi` editor, where you can change `spec.type` to `ClusterIP` or just remove it as default type for Kubernetes service is `ClusterIP` so if it won't be specified, Kubernetes will automatically use `ClusterIP`.

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        25s
my-nginx     LoadBalancer   10.107.129.201   <pending>     80:30173/TCP   8s
minikube-new:~$ kubectl edit svc my-nginx
service/my-nginx edited
sekreta@minikube-new:~$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP   46s
my-nginx     ClusterIP   10.107.129.201   <none>        80/TCP    29s
```

2. **kubectl patch**

`$ kubectl patch service <yourServiceName> -p '{"spec":{"type":"ClusterIP"}}'`

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        10m
my-nginx     LoadBalancer   10.107.129.201   <pending>     80:30456/TCP   2m
minikube-new:~$ kubectl patch service my-nginx -p '{"spec":{"type":"ClusterIP"}}'
service/my-nginx patched
minikube-new:~$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP   10m
my-nginx     ClusterIP   10.107.129.201   <none>        80/TCP    3m
```

3. **kubectl apply**

You can edit your Yaml and remove `spec.type` or have 2 Yamls with `ClusterIP` and `LoadBalancer` and switch them depends on your needs.

```
$ kubectl apply -f svc.yaml 
service/my-nginx configured
minikube-new:~$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP   22m
my-nginx     ClusterIP   10.111.237.133   <none>        80/TCP    16s
```

4. Use some 3rd party software to make changes in your cluster like [Helm](https://helm.sh/) and using templates.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it gave me great intuition about how those resources could be managed. My minikube with k8s version **1.18** rejected kubectl commands to change the type to `ClusterIP`, so I decided to increase the version.